# Hibernate: How to specify @ColumnDefault for Column of type enum

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an enum defined as follows:

```java
public enum TRAFFIC_SOURCE {
    IP, CLIENT_ID, MOBILE
}
```

And in my repository:

```java
@Column(name = "SOURCE")
@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TRAFFIC_SOURCE source;
```

Now I want to specify default value for the column. I tried two things, getting errors in both cases:

```java
@ColumnDefault(TRAFFIC_SOURCE.IP)
// Error:(26, 43) java: incompatible types: com.myproj.enums.TRAFFIC_SOURCE cannot be converted to java.lang.String

@ColumnDefault(TRAFFIC_SOURCE.IP.name())
// Error:(26, 51) java: element value must be a constant expression
```

forcing me to use

```java
@ColumnDefault("IP")
```

Is there a way to use Enum variable as default?

Comment: Did you try to initialize the `source` variable with the enum value ou want by default? This way, the model should instanciate the variable with the value when creating the object: `private TRAFFIC_SOURCE source = TRAFFIC_SOURCE.IP;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the @ColumnDefault only takes a String as argument and the value in an annotation must be a constant, the only possibility is to use

```
@ColumnDefault("IP")
```

If you are not forced to have the default value on the table column and always insert data with JPA then you could initialize the field as Kapcash said:

```
private TRAFFIC_SOURCE source = TRAFFIC_SOURCE.IP;
```